# Visual problems after today's update (23 Jul 2015)

Tags: graphic-drivers, updates

I have updated elementary OS one hour ago and I noticed really weird visual behavior with some elements. In Chrome, most of the times my context menu is black, but not always. When opening a new tab the bookmarks line is black.

Before the update everything was perfect.

**Edit**: Looks like the problem is only in Google Chrome

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this happen with other applications as well or only Google Chrome?

Comment: Looks like it is only in Chrome

Comment: Do you know by chance if the last update contained a new Chrome version then?

Comment: This is the update which brought the problem http://pastebin.com/90t9jCby

Comment: Which version of Chrome do you have installed? Is it from a ppa or did you install it from a deb via Chrome's website?

Comment: I downloaded the deb from Google's website.

Comment: I too see this black menu on Chrome but only for a second. It happened after I switched video drivers from Nouveau to proprietary (Nvidia-331). Try accessing 'Additional controllers' or 'Additional drivers' or howewer it is called in english, and select a different driver.

Comment: I guess the switch from Nouveau to NVIDIA 331.113 solved the issue. Add your comment as answer so I can accept it @Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too see this black menu on Chrome but only for a second.

It happened after I switched video drivers from Nouveau to proprietary (Nvidia-331).

Try accessing 'Additional controllers' or 'Additional drivers' (howewer it is called in english) and select a different driver.